# Time required for mod operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Let $x,y,n$ be $1234567809, 12345, 9087654321$. My laptop can perform 1 64-bit mod operation in 1 microsecond. Estimate the number of seconds needed for each of the following:
>
> 1. Find $x^y \pmod{n}$
> 2. Find $t$ such that $x^t \equiv 2672633475 \pmod{n}$.

I guess around 10^45 digits, am I right and how do I calculate time from here?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but just answering homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you want to calculate $1234567809^{12345}$ modulo 9087654321, you do *not* start by calculating $1234567809^{12345}$. After every operation, you reduce the result modulo 9087654321.

Hint 2: You can calculate $x^{12345}$ with about 25 multiplications, not 12345.

Hint 3: Probably less than 10 seconds for the last question if you find factors of n first, and use brute force and a tiny bit of maths (but that answer won't do you any good if you can't find that tiny bit of maths).